# MySQL column defaults -  advantages/disadvantages and should I use for all columns?

Tags: mysql, null, default, default-value

1) What are the advantages and disadvantages of supplying a default value for columns in a table?

2) Furthermore, should **all** columns have default values? I mean, seems like a good idea... why not? :)

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) What are the advantages and disadvantages of supplying a default value for columns in a table?

Advantages are that you can set the default, rather than using the standard default.  This also simplifies insert statements in that you don't need to specify so many values.

No real disadvantages as long as you have reasonable defaults.

> 2) Furthermore, should all columns have default values? I mean, seems like a good idea... why not? :)

This really depends on your business logic.  For instance if there is a column like CUSTOMER_NAME which you could not possibly come up with a good default value, then you should not specify a default.  But for other columns like ACTIVE or DELETED that could be true or false, you should probably specify a default.

I hope this answers your questions.

Answer (score 4):

ADVANTAGES:

- When using referential integrity / foreign keys (one column in a table  points to a column in another table), you are able to set no link for a column by setting the foreign key column to NULL. For example if you have a table of families and one column points to a table of kids, if a family has no kids, the kids column can be NULL.
- Gives you an extra state should you need it, eg. empty string and not used.

DISADVANTAGES

- Uses up an additional bit of memory on each row in the dataset, it does not save memory, it uses more if a column allows NULL values.
- There is an extra state apart from 0 or an empty string the programmer has to deal with.

**The golden rule is do not allow NULL columns unless you need them.**

Answer (score 3):

All columns will have a default value, whether you specify it or not. If you don't specify, it will simply use the *default* default value for that type.

For a column that allows nulls, the default value will be NULL. For a default value that doesn't allow NULLs, an INTEGER column, for example, will have a default value of 0.

You should specify a default value when you want something other than the *default* default value.

Default values get applied only when you `INSERT` a new record.

A good use case for a default value is to enforce the least privilege paradigm in security.

If you have boolean (TINYINT) fields in your ACL table such as "allowUpdates" andd "allowDeletes", then you should default these to FALSE (0), so that when a new user is created, they will get the least privileges until you specifically set them.

If you follow the least privilege paradigm, then an attacker cannot trick the system into giving him high privileges simply by tricking the system into creating a new user account.

So, the disadvantages could be serious if you don't choose proper defaults. The advantages are that you can override the defaults to a sane value for your application.

Other advantages include that when inserting a record, if you want the default value for a particular field, you can simply not set it. This can make your query shorter and simpler. Also, it lets the configuration be handled in the database. In other words, you can change the defaults (in the database) without changing the application.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response!

Answer (score 1):

Default values are really about data quality and the future use of the information.

Data Quality includes having sensible, thought out defaults.

Having nulls, nils and blanks tends to cause a lot of problems 'down the line' when the data needs to be used, manipulated and analyzed.

Data that can have a specific set of values will usually benefit from having a default.

Data that is truly free text, e.g. issue_details may not have a default, but if a default is used, for example "`not given`" it provides a more specific value that can be searched for, exclude in searches and will generally give less problems when used in the future.
Conversely, and also to address your second point, in cases where a value IS required and a default is NOT appropriate, e.g user_last_name, then a default should NOT be used.

Defaults in other areas can be a good way to emphasize to all users of the data what the intent was.  For example, with a column called 'known issues',  The default might be 'none' which would be more accurate and useful than null.